# How do i make it so each image/button is in a column?

Tags: html, css

I am making a test site and I want to get these images/buttons into a left to right column, if you know how and could help me I would be grateful. I've tried to google it but it comes up dry and I've tried it but I'm not that good at editing my code.

```
<div class='box'>

    <form action="/naruto_shippuden">
      <input type="image" src="images/naruto_shippuden.jpg" alt="Submit" width="100" height="150">
      <h6 class='txt'><b>Naruto Shippuden</b></h6>
    </form>

    <form action="/naruto">
      <input type="image" src="images/naruto.jpg" alt="Submit" width="100" height="150">
      <h6 class='txt'><b>Naruto</b></h6>
    </form>

    <div align='right'>
      <form action="/Deathnote/">
        <input type="image" src="images/naruto.jpg" alt="Submit" width="100" height="150">
        <h6 class='txt'><b>Deathnote</b></h6>
      </form>
    </div>
    
  </div>
```

Thanks.

- LiamC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `display: flex` to your div .box class

what I did:

```
<div class='box' style='display: flex'>
```

Comment: After that do you know how i make it not bunch up? because after i did that it is all smushed together

Comment: You can make stop it bunching up by adding a margin to the form class or like the below mentioned

Answer (score 0):

Add `display: flex` like mentioned above and also add `justify-content: space-between` to stop them bunching up.

Guide to flexbox below:
https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

```
<div class='box' style='display: flex; justify-content: space-between'>
```

You could also try; space-around, space-evenly or space-between for the justify-content property value